@ not escaped by url.PathEscape
I'm wondering why using url.PathEscape is not escaping the "@" character.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
)

func main() {
    path := url.PathEscape("dm@b.com")
    fmt.Println(path) //dm@b.com
}

I understand the @ character is reserved for the path component of an URI, why is it not escaping it?

Nafaik. To the best of my knowledge, the @ sign is reserved in the authority component as a divider between the user info subcomponent and the host subcomponent. There was one application server or CMS which made heavy use of @ signs in the path component and queries... Can't remember which one.

What is interesting is that url.PathUnescape does unescape %40 which represents the encoding for @

That doesn't mean anything, url.PathUnescape unescapes all %-codes. For example it unescapes %41 to 'A' even though A obviously has no special meaning.

Here:
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.3
"@" is explicitly specified as one of the valid components of a path segment, so there is no need to escape it.
